# lcdf typetools- kpathsea library not found

Tags: texlive, paths, file-lookup

I am not sure this is the right place, but considering that involves a tex-based library, I hope so.

I am on ubuntu 14.04, texlive 2014 manually installed (on `/media/pierpaolo/Seagate/texlive_linux/bin/x86_64`)

I am trying to install lcdf typetools to install Minion Pro font. As per instructions, running the file ./configure, I got the following error:

```
[...]
checking kpathsea/kpathsea.h usability... no
checking kpathsea/kpathsea.h presence... no
checking for kpathsea/kpathsea.h... no
checking for kpse_set_program_name in -lkpathsea... no
configure: error: 
=========================================

I can't find the kpathsea library and/or header files. Tell me where to look
using the --with-kpathsea=PREFIX option (header files should be under
PREFIX/include/kpathsea, and library under PREFIX/lib), or disable support
using --without-kpathsea.
```

kpathsea commands like kpsewhich are obviously present and working, but where library and header files are? Are they present at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, lcdf-typetools are included in TeX Live, so no need to recompile them.

Second, TeX Live does not provide any library installation of libkpathsea, that means you have to do it yourself, or install libkpathsea-dev from the ubunu repository.

But I really suggest using the lcdf-typetools shipped with TL2014.